# QGIS Plugin Overlay Analysis Stuck

Tags: qgis, overlay

I am a bit new in p\Pthon programming in QGIS. Now, I am trying to develop a QGIS Plugin about Suitability Analysis using Ordered Weighted Averaging process. So in brief, I want to make a plugin to produce a single map overlayed from several maps/layers and also assigned with user-based preference weight.

The idea, the plugin will provide the user to input several layers, and the user can assign their preference weight numbers.

[image]

Now, I am only able to create the UI and have succeeded to manage how to input the data. But I am stuck what is the next step? How to design the weight for each layers, and how to perform the overlay analysis itself?

Comment: So you're asking how to code the entire core function of your plugin? Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: In general yes! Or where I can learn from the existing code about a similar case? Thank you so much for your response!

Comment: I suggest using the processing framework and developing a processing [plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/processing.html) or [script](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html).  The main advantage of this is that QGIS creates the GUI for you.  I recommend starting with a processing script (here's a [template](https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/)) before progressing to a full processing plugin.